# Ciclo for en la vista de Ionic?

Tags: ionic, angular, ionic3, ionic-framework

me ah surgido una duda  y es que quiero  imprimir un elemento en la vista de ionic   una  cantidad de veces según una variable numérica

digamos :

```html
public numero = 4;
```

luego en la vista intente hacer una especie de ciclo con `*ngFor` pero sin resultados (por que por lo general lo utilizo con Arrays)

Luego investigue un poco y leei sobre  `ngrepeat`

Quiero imprimir una estrella según el numero que le envié es decir si le envió un cuatro imprimir cuatro estrellas

```html
 <ion-icon ng-repeat="i in numero"  color="yellow" ios="ios-star" md="md-star" ></ion-icon>
```

Comment: esta pregunta es exactamente lo que buscas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535629/repeat-html-element-multiple-times-using-ngfor-based-on-a-number?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intenta esto,debería funcionar
Html:

```
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number)"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></li>
    </ul>
```

en el controler

```
  $scope.number = 5;
    $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);   
    }
```

te pongo un enlace donde lo explican mejor :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array

Comment: Creo que ng-repeat es para Ionic en su primera versión (con AngularJS, no con Angular)